# TwitteR scraping with R error, fixing ideas?

Tags: r, web-scraping, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I'm a bit desperate with my problem as I checked all the existing sources and nothing worked for me.

The issue:

I'm trying to scrape twitter with R in Rstudio, I'm on the very first stage of auth with API keys:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(openssl)
library(httpuv)
library(devtools)
origop <- options("httr_oauth_cache")
options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)

api_key <- "*****"
api_secret <- "******"
access_token <- "*****"
access_secret <- "******"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

I'm using keys with essential access, v2 access level (which in theory shouldn't be the reason for the bug, but who knows?..)

---

**This code gives the error:**

```
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

**What I tried:**

**1.** Restarting the session after installing the packages

**2.** Fixing httr bug by running:

```
 library(devtools)
devtools::install_version("httr", version="0.6.0", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

**3.** Fixing possible compatibility issue by running:

```
devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")
```

**4.** running all of the above, restarting R and even restarting the laptop 3 times.

**5.** Checked my firewall - it's off.

**6.** Checked my default browser and being logged in in it into twitter - done.

**7.** Tried re-generating my access keys and re-running all of the above - didn't help.

I don't know what else to try, does anybody have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: if you just call `setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret)` does it open a browser for you to login?

Comment: nope, it gives me an error: Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the `twitteR` package rather than the more actively maintained [rtweet](https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/)?

Comment: no, not at all. It's actually my first ever attempt to scrape twitter at all, I know nothing about which package is better, I was just trying to follow some steps I found an article on.

Comment: I tried using rtweet now and it gives me an error as well : Error: Twitter API failed [403]. I checked what this error means:   
Forbidden.  V2
The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why. Check that your developer account includes access to the endpoint you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted (e.g. Engagement API or Ads API) or sign up for access.

Comment: I don't understand the part of getting my app allowlisted.. I'm just using the lightest free version that in theory doesn't need any extra validation or approval

Comment: I've applied for elevated access after reading some more about it, hopefully this will solve the issue. Thank you for giving an alternative idea :)

Comment: What function are you calling when you get that error? Every request needs to be authenticated. How exactly did you set up your application. Also see the info at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/auth.html

Comment: I used token <- rtweet::create_token(app =   "the name of my app"
consumer_key = "***",
consumer_secret = "**",
access_token = "***",
access_secret = "***").   and then I ran search_tweets() like this: tweet <- search_tweets(query,
                       n = 1000,
                       include_rts = FALSE,
                       retryonratelimit = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Aright, so after some checking here's the solution (if anybody ever needs it):

1. use library (rtweet)
2. apply and get approved for elevated access. That was definitely the problem that didn't let me go ahead.